# pybind11: passing numpy array to c++ by value/reference

Tags: python, numpy, pybind11

Here is my function signature

```
auto fun(py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> x)
```

The problem is that when passing array of `np.float64`, the array is not copied and can be modified in `fun` (which is not expected), when passing array of `np.float32` or other dtype, it's copied.

My question is that is there a way to force copy of `x` even if its dtype is `np.float64`.